# Cannot connect QMainWindow and QDialog

Tags: user-interface, qt4

I have a QMainWindow displaying a QDialog:

```
CalibrationDialog d(this);
d.exec();
```

My QMainWindow class has a signal:

```
signals:
void PenOn( QPoint p );
```

And QDialog has a slot:

```
public slots:
void on_PenON( QPoint p );
```

I tried connecting PenOn event to on_PenOn in two ways:

1. After instantiating QDialog

```
   void MainWindow::on_actionC_triggered()
   {
     appState = CALIBR;

     CalibrationDialog d(this);
     connect( this, SIGNAL(PenOn(QPoint)), &d,SLOT(on_PenOn(QPoint)) );
     d.exec();
   }
```

2. In QDialog constructor

```
    CalibrationDialog::CalibrationDialog(QWidget *parent) :
        QDialog(parent),
        ui(new Ui::CalibrationDialog)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);

        [...]

        connect( parent, SIGNAL(PenOn(QPoint)), this,SLOT(on_PenOn(QPoint)) );
    }
```

None of this works :(.
I'm emitting PenOn signal from MainWindow slot activated by another thread.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does Qt print anything out when you try to make the connection?  What does it say?  (You might need to build in debug mode to get the printout.)  I assumed this was just a typo in the question the first time, but I now see that you declare your slot as "on_PenON" (with an uppercase final N) and try to use it as "on_PenOn" (with a lowercase final n).  If this is the same as in your code, that is the problem, as signal/slots are case-sensitive.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't remember and I don't have the old code, I tried to do it once more with proper functions and it does not work. I do not remember no error messages (from compiler) - everything was done in debug mode.

Comment: Just to be clear about things, Qt in debug mode may print out a message when it tries to connect to the signal *when you run the program*, not when you compile it.  The connection is treated as a run-time thing, so the compilation will succeed even if the connection is incorrect.  Other than that, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @Caleb: Thank you for your interest, I tried to reproduce the problem creating a small application and I cannot. I think I have done something wrong maybe just by messing up with threads. I thing the thread may be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a blocking direct connection, although be aware that the slot will be executed in the MainWindow's thread:

`connect(this, SIGNAL(PenOn(QPoint)), &d, SLOT(on_PenOn(QPoint)), Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);`

See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum for more info.

The problem with using the default Qt::ConnectionType for the connect method is that since the objects are in different threads, the slot will not be called until the dialog thread gets back to it's main loop, which will only happen after the d.exec() loop is finished.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work too. I'm a bit confused by exec() method. The parent window still receives and processes signals from working thread when exec is triggered (that's ok) so I don't understand why the dialog windows does not receive main window signals. After some debugging in 
/*!\internal
 */
void QMetaObject::activate

        if ((sender->d_func()->connectedSignals[n] & m) == 0)
            // nothing connected to these signals, and no spy
            return;
returns true and method returns.

Comment: There should be no problem with different threads here, as both classes are UI classes, and must be in the same (first) thread.  The type of connection for that signal should default to direct, which would call it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Still does not know what's going on. I made use of QEvent and solved problem this way.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess on the problem is that you don't have the Q_OBJECT macro in one of your classes, or possibly both.  If you do but added it after you generated your makefile, you may need to re-run `qmake` to regenerate the makefile (or whatever you use on your platform) to let it know that the `moc` needs to be run on those classes.  If the `moc` isn't run over your classes, it doesn't generate the code required to add the signal and slot information to the class, and the connections will fail.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately both classes have Q_OBJECT macro, in fact, both headers were generated by Qt Designer, I tried remaking the whole project too. Still no success. Fortunately sending event works as a charm.